# Data Table pagination not working,,

Tags: javascript, php, datatable

Having trouble with datatable's pagination. All data displays in single page. How do i limit the rows by 10?

JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.ajax({
    url   : 'views/logs/reldata.php' ,
    // type : "GET";

    success :  function(data)
       {
         // alert(data);


            $("#media_tbl").empty();
            $('#media_tbl').DataTable( {
               'searching': true,
                "destroy": true,
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "paging": true,
                "length": 10,
                "ajax" : 'views/logs/reldata.php',
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "act_type" },
                    { "data": "action" },
                    { "data": "actor" },
                    { "data": "date_created" }
                ]


            });
            // setInterval( function () {
            //       $('#media_tbl').DataTable().ajax.reload();
            // }, 30000 );
      }
  });
});
```

PHP code:

```
    $dispo = array(
      'draw' => 9,
      'recordsTotal' => (int)$coun['cou'],
      'recordsFiltered' => (int)$coun['cou'],
      'data' => $disp
);


$dispo = json_encode($dispo);

print $dispo;
```

Having trouble with datatable's pagination. All data displays in single page. How do i limit the rows by 10?
Thank you for help :D

Comment: take a plugin which has a pagination facilty so  it will take by default per page 10

Comment: @suresh Datatables is already a plugin that has pagination facility.

Comment: You have switched on `serverSide` which tells Datatables that you want to manage Paging yourself (via the Server). Turn that off if you want to let DT do the paging clientside.

Comment: why do you have 2 `ajax` request if you are already getting the data from the parent `ajax` request then simply assign the data in the `Jquery datatable`  as `$('#media_tbl').DataTable( {"data":data,....other properties});`

Comment: @Jeff thanks ,, that worked well. Im still unfamiliar with DT lol. anyway thanks :D